# SQL - GO in IF Condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, if-statement, sql-scripts

I need to make a SQL-Script, which can be executed multiple times on the same DB, to check if a table already exists. If yes don't do anything, if no create the table and insert some data. The problem is, that I can't use 'GO' inside the BEGIN and END tags.

What I need (Code doesn't work):

```
    IF (OBJECT_ID('dbo.Report', 'U') IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Report](
            [ReportID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Report_ReportID_1]  DEFAULT (newid()),
            [Name] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
            [Description] [ntext] NULL,
            [Query] [ntext] NULL,
            CONSTRAINT [PK_Reporting] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
            (
                [ReportID] ASC
            )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
            ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY];
        )
        GO   

        INSERT [dbo].[Report] ([ReportID], [Name], [Description], [Query]) VALUES (N'1', N'04. People and groups', N'People and groups', N'select * from V_REPORT04USERGROUPS order by Login')
        GO

    END
    GO
```

Can someone tell me the most clean way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Please tag dbms product used.

Comment: GO is a batch separator. It is NOT a SQL command.

Comment: And you don't need GO in this script at all. Also as zedfoxus noted add ; to your statements.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, seems like I missed that in the whole SQL-Script stuff

Comment: You should avoid the ntext datatype. It has been deprecated since sql 2005. You should instead use nvarchar(max).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and make sure you provide a datatype for reportID

```
IF (OBJECT_ID('dbo.Report1', 'U') IS NULL)
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Report1](
        [ReportID] int NULL,
        [Name] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
        [Description] [ntext] NULL,
        [Query] [ntext] NULL
    );

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Report1] ([ReportID], [Name], [Description], [Query]) VALUES (N'1', N'04. People and groups', N'People and groups', N'select * from V_REPORT04USERGROUPS order by Login');

END
GO
```

Comment: @vkp Oh yes, `INSERT INTO` - caught the missing int but forgot the `INTO`. Nice eye. Thank you.

Comment: I shortened my create table (to make the code a bit more clear to show on here) and accidentally deleted the Datatype for the ReportID. Thanks your solution seems to work pretty well

Answer (score 0):

```
IF (OBJECT_ID('dbo.Report', 'U') IS NULL)
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Report](
        [ReportID] NULL,
        [Name] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
        [Description] [ntext] NULL,
        [Query] [ntext] NULL
    );


    INSERT [dbo].[Report] 
    ([ReportID], [Name], [Description], [Query]) 
    VALUES 
    (N'1', N'04. People and groups', N'People and groups', 
     N'select * from V_REPORT04USERGROUPS order by Login');

END
```

All columns accepting NULL and no Primary Key?

Comment: Accidentally deleted too much of the 'Create table' statement to keep the code clear to show it off on here. I edited to post with the original create statement. Thanks for the feedback!